# Split boxes to enter number for same Id

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Hi I have below form field to enter Tax Id. I was wondering how can i split it so that first box takes only 2 digits an than second 7 with "-" i.e 44-2234233

```
    <div class="form">
        <label class="form1" for="o_taxId">Tax Id</label>
        <input type="number" class="medium" id="o_taxId" name="taxId" />
    </div>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-do-an-input-with-a-mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery you can do this:

```
<div class="form">
    <label class="form1" for="o_taxId">Tax Id</label>
    <input type="number" class="medium" id="o_taxId" name="taxId" size="2" maxlength="2" />
    <input type="number" class="medium" id="o_taxId2" name="taxId2" size="7" maxlength="7" />
</div>
<script>
$('#o_taxId').bind('input', function() { 
    var length1 = $(this).val().length;
    if (length1 === 2) {
        $('#o_taxId2').focus();
    }
});
</script>
```

this swaps focus autocratically to the second field when you type in the first, but if you don't need that you can remove the script.