# Input field for bank account number

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create form input field for inputing bank account number. Than number has `max` = 18 number and `min` 18 numbers.

algorithm is next  (3+13+2)

So i cant use clasic input text box i need special text box where i will have slash that separates that numbers like on screenshot:

[image]

How can i create textbox like above using `javascript` and `html`

Comment: So search the net for masked input

Comment: Whay question is down voted?  I dont know what is wrong in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to this question: [How to implement an input with a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask)

The selected answer includes a link to a [jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) that would work like this for your example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#field").mask("999 - 9999999999999 - 99");
});
```

Of course javascript can't solve everything and inputs should be [validated server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation) as well.

Answer (score 1):

sometime ago I used a pluggin named "formatter.js" it is really easy to use, I will give you and example:

```
var formatted = new Formatter(document.getElementById('elementToFormat'), {
  'pattern': '{{999}}-{{9999999999999}}-{{99}}',
  'persistent': true
});
```

you can find that library to download and find the documentation in the following link, [here](http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/index.html) or you can install that with bower

```
bower install formatter
```