# Fixed time format for textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net

I have a textBox1 which should take Fixed Format like eg below

HH:MM:SS or **:**:__

where HH,MM,SS can be entered but colon(:) should be fixed.Please help me out.

Comment: why not a masked textbox like this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask)?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Forms, or MVC? Either way, you could use a regular expression to check the format quite easily. e.g. `^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$` should work. If it's Forms, use a RegularExpressionValidator control along with the textbox to define it. If it's MVC use a Data Annotation Validator on the field in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use Mask plugin , i think it will serve you 
see this link 
  https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

download it from here 
https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Comment: this is futile without corresponding server-side validation. It's fine for enhancing the user experience, but cannot be a substitute for properly validating the input on the server - anything client-side can be bypassed or disabled by malicious users or bots.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
new Formatter(document.getElementById('date-input'), {
'pattern': '{{99}}/{{99}}/{{9999}}',
'persistent': true
});
```

or

```
$('#date-input').formatter({
'pattern': '{{99}}/{{99}}/{{9999}}',
'persistent': true
});
```

Comment: where should i use this code

Comment: in your <script></script>

Comment: this is pointless without matching server-side validation