# html Phone mask

Tags: javascript, html, mask

I want to add phone mask to my input. I found way how to do that, but it substring number "9". How can I make visible number "9". I need this  view `+994(__)___-__-__`

```js
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "+994(##) ###-##-##"}, { "mask": "+994(##) ###-##-##"}];
    $('#textbox').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='textbox' />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement an input with a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask)

Comment: @FotisGrigorakis do not see answer of my question in that topic.

Comment: @FotisGrigorakis Checked, the post has nothing to do with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [escapeChar](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#escapechar):

> escapeChar: "\\"

add this before digit 9 and it will escape 9 in the mask.

```js
$(window).load(function()
{
   var phones = [{ "mask": "+\\9\\94(##) ###-##-##"}, { "mask": "+994(##) ###-##-##"}];
    $('#textbox').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='textbox' />
```

Comment: You are awesome!) Perfect, Thank you!)