# Mask const string in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, mask

I have in my app `const string number_MASK = "000-000"`, and in my `html`, on the input something like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Number #" data-mask="@Constants.number_MASK">
```

Is there a way to change the mask so when user enters some random number like `599563` to input value to be **005-995** ?

I specifically need two first letters of the string to be 00

Comment: You're going to have to write this in Javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement an input with a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask)

Comment: @Liam or check for a javascript API that implements it, check the duplicated question linked for both approaches

Comment: using this https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html