# Automatic number space in the input form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have seen the possibility to limit the way the text will show in a form. For instance, if it's a credit card, when the user writes, automatically a space is created between 4 numbers. How to do that?

(I am not talking about regex validation when the user click submit but before that, when the user writes the numbers in the input)

```html
<form action='externs/select-insert.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='card' name='card' value='### ###'>
</form>
```

Comment: What you're looking for might be [input masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform that this way, using `EventListener` and a `replace` modification of the input value on `keydown` ( not `change` because it will be triggered only when `input` is not on `focus` anymore )

```js
document.querySelector('#card').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/(\d{4})(\d+)/g, '$1 $2')
})
/* Jquery */
$('#card').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d{4})(\d+)/g, '$1 $2'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='externs/select-insert.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='card' name='card' value='### ###'>
</form>
```

Comment: This snippet will not work if you occult numbers using a non numeric symbol (which will probably be the case). Simply change the `d` in the replace by your matching character.

Comment: I try to adapt that to jQuery and I have problems, can you help?